# Sails js - waterline ORM limit or sort after group by?

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I am using Waterline ORM for sails.js. `limit` and `sort` are not working when you use `groupby`, but are working fine when you dont do any grouping .

For example

```
Model.find({
    groupBy:['term'],
    sum:['count'],
    limit:20,
    sort :'count DESC'}).exec(function(error,response){
        if(error) res.json(error);
        res.json(response);
    });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
Model.find()  
 .groupBy('term') 
 .sum('count')  
 .limit(20)
 .sort({count: 'desc'}) 
 .exec(function (err, data){
 //Your code here..
});
```

Comment: Use `sort` before `groupBy`.. May be this would work.. I hope the above mentioned method is not giving any errors..?

Comment: tried that one too . Your method is not giving any errors its just displaying all the results .

Comment: That means you are not applying the right filters.. Can you please update your question with your model and Controller files.. i.e `api/models/Foo.js` and `api/controller/whateverController.js`

Comment: Try replacing 'asc'/'desc' with 1/-1, thus: .sort({count: -1}).

Comment: is there like toSql method in sails to see our query ?

Comment: "The `groupBy` clause is no longer supported in Sails/Waterline. the usage has changed.  Now, to run aggregate queries using the `groupBy` operator, use a native query instead." Sailsjs debugger said

Comment: In v1+ groupBy is not supported  See official document https://sailsjs.com/documentation/upgrading/to-v-1-0#changes-to-waterline-criteria-usage

Answer (score 0):

**Example override toJSON**

```
    // Your Model
    module.exports = {
        attributes: {
            // some attributes here
            name: 'string',
            email: 'string',
            password: 'string',

            // Override .toJSON instance method
            toJSON: function() {
                var obj = this.toObject();
                delete obj.password;
                return obj;
           }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this :**

```
  Model.find()  
   .sort({count: 'desc'}) 
   .groupBy('term') 
   .exec(function (err, data){
   //Your code here..
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In sails-mongo, for sorting ASC and DESC we can use same like mongo,
For an example, if you want to fetch count in `DESC` order then the query is like,

```
Model.find({
 sort: {
    count: 0(Note:- Here 0 for DESC and 1 for ASC)
  }
})
```

Hope it will work for you.