# How get attributes by postcode and sort by open = true

Tags: sails.js

I've got Android application when I got a result by postcode. I need to get a result by postcode and sort by open.

How I can GET URL in sails js

http://192.168.1.8:1337/restaurant?postcode=LE36Rl?sort=open

Doesn't working

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Five guys",
    "category": "chineese",
    "address": "11 Castle street, Leicester, LE1 5WN",
    "postcode": "LE36RL",
    "logo": "https://fastly.4sqi.net/img/general/128x128/87388367_WyFLstNZmvbSC7jEyYvd4UYsrleRfPm8fL1ar5Vp_ps.png",
    "open": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Japan Master",
    "category": "chineese",
    "address": "11 Castle street, Leicester, LE1 5WN",
    "postcode": "le36rl",
    "logo": "https://www.brandcrowd.com/gallery/brands/pictures/picture14867764381797.png",
    "open": true
  },
```

Comment: do u need this?? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539468/sails-js-waterline-orm-limit-or-sort-after-group-by

Comment: Probably  I need something like this, but I can find information about waterline but I cannot understand where I need to put this code. Could you show me a way where I can read how to use waterline? Thank you so much

Comment: I read dox on this link https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/tree/master/concepts/ORM